# Command 'ntpdc' not found

Tags: kali-linux, ntp

When I issue the command `ntpdc` it throw me errors, I already `sudo apt-get install ntp`, and still no result.

```
ntpdc -nc
Command 'ntpdc' not found, did you mean:
  command 'ntpd' from deb ntpsec
  command 'ntpd' from deb openntpd
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

[image: anyone know how to fix this?]

Comment: Welcome! https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ : *"Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux."* - And unfortunately many questions referring Kali seem to be asked by people relatively unfamiliar with Linux, not  professional penetration testers and security specialists and/or not about [managing information technology systems in a business environment](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Kali linux does not have package `ntp`, but [`ntpsec`](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/ntpsec) imported from Debian's [`ntpsec`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ntpsec).

That package does not contain [`ntpdc`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpdc), but similar [`ntpq`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpq):

```
$ apt-file show ntpsec | grep -E "/usr/(s)?bin"
ntpsec: /usr/bin/ntpmon
ntpsec: /usr/bin/ntpq
ntpsec: /usr/bin/ntptrace
ntpsec: /usr/sbin/ntpd
ntpsec: /usr/sbin/ntpkeygen
ntpsec: /usr/sbin/ntpleapfetch
ntpsec: /usr/sbin/ntptime
ntpsec: /usr/sbin/ntpwait
```

The [`ntpq`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpq) also has the `-c command` option:

> `-c`
> The following argument is interpreted as an interactive format command and is added to the list of commands to be executed on the specified host(s). Multiple `-c` options may be given.

However, `ntpdc` conflicts with `systemd-timesyncd`, both providing `time-daemon`, which is probably installed by default to handle the time synchronization. There you would have  `timedatectl timesync-status`, but not the ability to run commands.

---

Your goal was actually an *XY problem*: you wanted to run tests for `monlist` [NTP amplification attacks](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/ntp-amplification-ddos-attack/). For that, you do not need `ntdpc` nor `ntpq`, but you can use [Nmap script `ntp-monlist`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ntp-monlist.html):

```
nmap -sU -pU:123 -Pn -n --script=ntp-monlist <target>
```

Comment: but i want to run Network Time Protocol Daemon (ntpd) monlist Command Enabled DoS
ntpdc -n -c monlist <IP>  in kali linux.

Comment: You could use this instead to retrieve that information: https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ntp-monlist.html